# "function 'AddDllDirectory' not found" while importing pytorch

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I keep getting this error while trying to import pytorch in jupyter notebook

```
import torch
```

> AttributeError: function 'AddDllDirectory' not found

this error occur only when I try installing pytorch in anaconda (I used both command to install pytorch pip and conda, I also tried installing only the cpu version and nothing changed, i still get the same error while trying to import it)

I searched the internet and found nothing remotely close to my problem.
is there's a way I can fix this error?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by installing the file (KB2533623) from 
[Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26764) (for windows 7 users). this file apparently contains the missing "AddDllDirectory" function.

Posting this answe in case someone ran into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. For sharing